# author name conventions: how to prevent misindexing?

Tags: arxiv, online-publication, google-scholar

**Fact:** Papers/preprints' indexing systems (e.g., arXiv, Scholar, Scopus, WOS, ProjectEuclid, etc.) *systematically* misindex and/or incorrectly display author names that do not correspond to the most common English name formats: "FirstName MiddleName Surname" or "FirstName MiddleName Surname1-Surname2". A typical example is the indexing of "Name Surname1 Surname2" as "Surname2, N[ame] S[urname1]".

Such misindexing (real-life examples in parentheses) *negatively affects some authors' careers*, and especially

- **authors' identification** ("So this paper is yours as well? But the author name [Surname2, N. S.] is different from your other papers [Surname1 Surname2, N.]. How so?")
- **authors' bibliometrics** (Some authors regularly spend their time with Scopus/Clarivate/Scholar clerks trying to convince them that they authored a certain paper and that their name is what they say it is, and not what some software thinks it is. This costs time and effort that could be invested otherwise, especially since, typically, each paper must be dealt with separately).
- **job opportunities (1)**, because misindexing has a disruptive effect on bibliometrics, and in turn because bibliometrics is related to academic profile/status.
- **job opportunities (2)**, because of the bibliometric requirements in some academic systems (e.g. the Italian ASN habilitation or the Russian VAK habilitation, the German habilitation in some universities for some fields)
- **the perception of authors in their community** ("Oh really? You have experienced such misindexing problems? Perhaps you should be more careful how you enter your name in the databases!")

**Question:** How, if at all possible, can one *prevent* such misindexing of their name from happening?
What steps can be taken to address this problem systematically and/or on a broad scale?

By "systematically" I mean "referring to a single author's publication list" (as opposed to "referring to a single misindexed paper"). By "broad scale" I mean "as a community effort, concerning more than one author at a time".

**Nonanswers:** I am aware of only one partially satisfactory solution: using a unique author identifier such as ORCID. In fact, in my experience, this just helped claiming authorship of misindexed papers, but does not prevent papers from being misindexed.

**Why this is a sensitive issue:** People identify themselves with their name more than with every other aspect of their lives (their community, their country, the color of their skin). In most cultures people *have* a name: **they do not *choose* to *use* that name** for registration purposes. Using a different name (e.g. dropping a second surname, removing a space, adding a hyphen) is *not an option*.

Let me provide some examples where misindexing is particularly diminishing:

- there are *single* surnames consisting of more words, and in which the same word can have a different meaning and bear different significance in the name. Example: "Dos Santos" vs "Dos Casas" (Spanish).
- there are *single* surnames in which the same word can be either a legitimate standalone name, or a per se meaningless particle. Example: "Dalla" vs "Dalla Casa" (Italian)
- there are *single* surnames consisting of article + name. Example: Le Fleur (French), El Hosseini (Arabic), etc.
- there are *single* (sur)names with a *meaning*: "ibn ʿAbd al-ʿAzīz" (Arabic) means "son of the Servant of the Almighty" (where "son of" is the standard patronymic particle, and "Almighty" is a theonym). Any misindexing of this name, such as "ibn", "ibn ʿAbd", "al-ʿAzīz" not only sounds ridiculous to any native speaker, but also turns the meaning into a potentially offensive one.

**What I believe is an origin of the problem:** It is well-understood that misindexing spreads and "reverberates". This is because most indexing systems import metadata from original sources (in my field of research: arXiv), without any form of consistency check. Example: Scholar imports metadata from arXiv; Elsevier submission "via arXiv" imports metadata from arXiv (and not always combines them correctly with the authors' data stored in Elsevier's EMSS).

This motivated addressing only the misindexing issue on arXiv in a previous version of this question (below).

---

arXiv "authors' name" field is well-known to behave poorly, especially for indexing purposes. In particular:

1. arXiv's conventions seem to be based on the standard English name format: "FirstName MiddleName Surname" or "FirstName MiddleName Surname1-Surname2". Nearly every name not satisfying this convention is misindexed. The foremost example is probably "FirstName Surname1 Surname2", which is usually indexed as if Surname1 were a middle name. Worst case scenario is the name format "FirstName SurnameParticle Surname":
   It seems that arXiv has an exception for "FirstName surnameParticle Surname" (note that here "surnameParticle" is lower case). For instance German surnames starting with "von" and Dutch names starting with "van" are indexed all right (actually, arXiv provides "John von Neumann" as an example), but nearly everything else falls in the 'misindexed' category. This especially includes most names with capitalized SurnameParticle's, as commonly found in romance languages, Semitic languages and others.
2. arXiv's research field removes first names when clicking on 'author' links. This forces to reenter the queried author's first name and is particularly damaging to people with common surnames.

Whereas these problems are both virtually well-known, it seems that nobody successfully lobbied to solve them. **Is there a way to do so? What attempts have been made?**
Supposing one were interested in addressing the matter, what would a good angle be? For instance, should one argue that arXiv's indexing system is bad for third-party databases (e.g. it propagates these sort of indexing errors to Scholar, etc.), or should one argue that arXiv is discriminating authors on a cultural basis?

While I have no insight in how exactly arXiv stores author names, I would expect that implementing names' parenthesization (as e.g. in BibTeX) would not be impossible. For instance, author names could be entered as

{SurnameAuthor1, NamesAuthor1} and {SurnameAuthor2, NamesAuthor2}

I understand this might be a gargantuan task – especially given arXiv's hardline on backwards compatibility –, but some compromise solutions might be implemented, such as fetching the correct names from ORCID profiles (at least for those authors who have one and linked it with arXiv).

Comment: ArXiv is free.  As a consequence, it has no money to do anything and any proposal had better be accompanied by a source of funding.  So the first part of a good angle is to find the money to pay for it.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I do see your point that what I am asking might be costly and I agree this would be the best way to go about it. However: (1) the alleged cost obviously depends on the current implementation. (2) Luckily, arXiv has a way of improving over time (thanks to its contributors); my question is rather how to prioritize what I perceive as a community's necessity, so that it can be addressed as funding allows. (3) Maybe it is just my perception, but I do feel that arXiv owes restitution to the authors whose names are misindexed. "It's free, so take it or leave it" doesn't cut it for me.

Comment: If you manage to convince the ArXiv board that this is important, then they have to turn around and go convince the people providing their pitifully small amount of funding that this is important.  It would be easier to cut out the middle step and go convince Simons (or maybe you can interest Ford or Mellon) that this is important.

Comment: Academia SE can’t do anything about it, so this reads as a rant not an answerable question.

Comment: @JonCuster I disagree. At the very least there might be Academia SE users who know more about arXiv name indexing and are willing to share their insights. As pointed out above, the difficulty in the implementation of what I am asking for is an important factor. Additionally, I am asking about what has been tried, which can hardly be construed as ranting. Finally, Academia SE is the perfect environment to survey whether this is perceived as a real necessity or rather just my personal fight against windmills. I think I am in good company though: https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/ap.html

Comment: @Dirakka - I just realized you might not be American and don't know how funding works in the US.  There is a long tradition in the US of very wealthy people donating some of their money to fund various activities.  For example, orchestras and museums in the US are funded mostly by private wealthy individuals, not governments.  About half of the funding for the ArXiv comes personally from Jim Simons, a multibillionaire and former math professor who left academia to start a hedge fund.  (He also is responsible for 10-20% or so of total research funding in pure math.)

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Indeed I am not American :) Thank you for your clarification. In my academic community there is some hope that arXiv will eventually replace journal publication altogether. Whereas this is currently an outlandish prospect (and one should be careful what one wishes for), maybe crowdfunding projects with such impact as the arXiv's might be a good start. I might add that, in the case of arXiv, the internationalization of its users' community calls for a more diverse funding as well, but that is my wishful thinking.

Comment: @Dirakka - Everyone would like ArXiv to have more diverse funding, but crowdfunding $1M a year every year (without some headline donors) hasn't been pulled off for too many things.

Comment: Even if multiple-past-name support were added to arXiv, the much much harder part would be retroactively reindexing existing papers.  ArXiv **does not know** which triple-named authors are using a middle name and which are using two last names.  Each of those names would have to be disambiguated manually.

Comment: _Finally, Academia SE is the perfect environment to survey whether this is perceived as a real necessity_ — As much as I sympathize with the question, this is the wrong platform for an opinion poll.

Comment: @JeffE *ArXiv does not know which triple-named authors are using a middle name and which are using two last names.* Yes, this is clear. It was also my reason to suggest a possible solution that involves ORCID (or any other id, for that matter). It is self-evident that willing arXiv users should contribute the task somehow (e.g. by reclaiming authorship of their preprints). However, depending on implementation, I think there is much room for automatism. For instance, author names could be converted to the new format upon association of the author profile with ORCID.

Comment: This is way, way too long. Also, be aware that old posts with no upvoted answers are likely to be automatically deleted, so I wouldn't put too much effort into maintaining this post (unless you think your changes could lead to it being reopened).

Comment: @cag51 Thank you for your comment: there was an error in a name translation and it seemed right to fix it. In fact, I did not understand why the question was closed in the first place, so I am not sure what to modify in order to have it reopened.

Comment: For one thing, it is way, way too long.

Answer (score -2):

Just use the standard BibTeX way out: "Last Names as you Want them Written, First Second Third Name". I.e., "de la Carrera y Cajal Rodríguez, José Miguel Antonio" (very much made-up Spanish name).

Comment: According to the guidelines, that would be interpreted as two authors: https://arxiv.org/help/prep#author: "Multiple author names should be separated with a comma"